# How to do order of operations in DrRacket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am putting equations into DrRacket and receiving a wrong answer because they are not entered in properly.

I have tried grouping the parenthesis in different orders and haven't fixed the problem yet.

The first line should read as: (100 / .0075)[ (1 + .0075)^37 -1]-100 = 4146.13

The second should read as: (2000 * .005)/[1 - (1 + .005)^11 -1]= 177.318
For the problems I get the output:
1.) 101.128...
2.) -10.563...

(/ 100 .0075(* (expt (+ 1 .0075) 37) (- 1)(- 100)))

(* 2000 .005(/(expt(+ 1 .005) 11)(- 1)))

Desired output:

1.) 4146.13

2.) 171.318

Comment: Fun fact: `(- x)` just negates the value `x`. eg. `(- 100) ; ==> -100`. Lisp doesn't do operator precedence so you need to do it explicitly. eg. `3 + 4 * 5` using PEMDAS rules does `(+ 3 (* 4 5))` and not `(* (+ 3 4) 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I translated those to:

```
(- (* (/ 100 .0075) (- (expt (+ 1 .0075) 37) 1)) 100)

(/ (* 2000 .005) (- (expt (+ 1 .005) 11) 1))
```

which correctly produce 4146.13 and 177.318